# jQuery - Is javascript excuted when wrapping HTML with $?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I presume that inline JavaScript bound to `orerror`, `onclick`, ... run.

But would a `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` element run javascript as well when wrapped with $(...) ?

---

If it does run is it sand-boxed?

---

**Sorry for the misunderstanding:**

Wanted to make sure that JavaScript loaded within the $ method would NOT run. I'm aware of other methods on how to load JavaScript scripts within the page and I generally use require.

Just wanted to figure out how much of a security risk wrapping HTML (containing script tags) within $ could be.

If someone can give me some insight/directions on how JavaScript is interpreted within the jQuery method that would give me my answer thanks.

---

Thanks :)

Comment: It's difficult to tell whats being asked here, what do you mean by "`<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` element run JS"?

Comment: I want to avoid JavaScript scripts from being executed when wrapped in $.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to write

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script> 
or 
if you use the html5 Doctype
<script></script>
```

when you want to execute Javascript. in your html files.

If you want to execute javascript without writing these tags then you need to add a extern .js file and link to that file like this:

```
<script src="pathtofile/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to avoid JavaScript running within jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Friend please excuse me if my understanding of the question was wrong.

if you wrap some code in `$()` it will consider it as either the javascript or jquery code. But as we know script is a tag not a javascript code, so finally it will be throwing an error.

In order to execute any code which is in script tag, please place the code in a file and use `getScript()` function of jquery by enclosing in `$()`. Finally your requirement might be met :).

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript(pathoffile);
});
```

Comment: Right, I meant to say $(<script></script>) will be throwing error :)